# Java/Android: Regexp or inversed

Tags: java, android, regex

I want to split my string into array in following rule:
substrings that fit a regexp and those, who don't. My regexp is `"\\[((id)|(club))[0-9]+\\|[^]]+\\]"`

For example, if I have a String `"Hi, [id123|Alex]!  Check out [club3123|this awesome club]! It's fantastic!"`

I want to get an array `["Hi, ", "[id123|Alex]", "! Check out ", "[club3123|this awesome club]", "! It's fantastic!"]`

I think, my regexp should be something like myregexp or not myregexp. I tried to google this, but no use. Please, help me.

Comment: I'd recommend checking out this site, and practice..http://www.regexr.com/ Your statement is quite, quite incorrect.

Comment: @Seidr don't understand, why are saying that it's incorrect. It successfully finds all substring like `[id123|Alex]` or `[club3123|this awesome club]`

Comment: You've edited your original question..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this regex in `Matcher#find`:

```
(\\[(?:id|club)[0-9]+[^]]+\\]|.+?(?=\\[(?:id|club)[0-9]+[^]]+\\]|$))
```

#### [Working Demo](http://regex101.com/r/nD0dE0)

**Explanation:** It matches text your given regex `\\[(?:id|club)[0-9]+[^]]+\\]` OR any arbitrary text of 1 or in length until your reges is found ahead using `lookahead` using `(?=\\[(?:id|club)[0-9]+[^]]+\\]|$)`.

Comment: Glad to know it worked out, can you please mark the answer as accepted by clicking on tick mark on top-left of my answer. I am adding explanation.

Comment: sorry for not clicking it earlier, stackoverflow didn't allow to do it earlier than in 3 minutes, so I left site for coding. Now, I've returned and with great pleasure marked your answer)